# Data from DynamoDB to EMR PySpark: object not serializable

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, emr

I have been trying to load data from DynamoDB to EMR spark application. I tried the method according to this post. https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1G4SQRV049UL0/Analyze-Your-Data-on-Amazon-DynamoDB-with-Apache-Spark

I could successfully reproduce the Scala code of this post (on a simple movie rating data). However, I would like to use PySpark instead of Scala. So I run

```
$pyspark --jars /usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar

conf = {"dynamodb.servicename": "dynamodb", "dynamodb.input.tableName":"myDynamoDBTable", "dynamodb.endpoint": "https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", "dynamodb.regionid":"us-east-1", "mapred.input.format.class":"org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat","mapred.output.format.class":"org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat"}

orders = sc.hadoopRDD(inputFormatClass="org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat", keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.Text", valueClass="org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable", conf=conf)
```

However, it caused an exception:

```
16/08/09 00:34:18 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8) had a not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable, value: {"item_id":{"n":"661"},"user_id":{"n":"1"},"info":{"m":{"time_stamp":{"s":"2016-08-08T16:46:14.920485"},"rating":{"n":"3"},"is_true":{"bOOL":true}}}})
- field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _2, type: class java.lang.Object)
- object (class scala.Tuple2, (,{"item_id":{"n":"661"},"user_id":{"n":"1"},"info":{"m":{"time_stamp":{"s":"2016-08-08T16:46:14.920485"},"rating":{"n":"3"},"is_true":{"bOOL":true}}}}))
- element of array (index: 0)
- array (class [Lscala.Tuple2;, size 1); not retrying
16/08/09 00:34:18 WARN ExecutorAllocationManager: No stages are running, but numRunningTasks != 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 703, in hadoopRDD
jconf, batchSize)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 933, in __call__
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 312, in get_return_value
.....
```

Could anyone please help me understand this error? I have been thinking about it for quite a while but no clue. I appreciate it!